# playframework-2.6: not enough arguments for method apply:

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I am using Play-Framework-2.6 i am getting this error 
 /myproject/app/controllers/Application.scala:151: not enough

```
arguments for method apply: (data: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString, _], contentLength: Option[Long], contentType: Option[String])play.api.http.HttpEntity.Streamed in object Streamed.
[error] Unspecified value parameters contentLength, contentType.
[error]         body = HttpEntity.Streamed(responseStream)
[error]                                   ^
```

here is my code

```
def prometheusMetrics = Action {
    val responseStream = Concurrent.unicast[Array[Byte]] { channel =>
      val writer = new WriterAdapter(channel)
      TextFormat.write004(writer, CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry.metricFamilySamples())
      writer.close()
    }
    Result(
     header = ResponseHeader(200, Map.empty),
        body = HttpEntity.Streamed(responseStream)
  ).as(TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004)
  }
```

i researched this but i did not find any suitable solution for it .please guide me

**Update # 1**
answer given by user @James Whiteley
after doing this

```
Result(
     header = ResponseHeader(200, Map.empty),
        body = HttpEntity.Streamed(responseStream, None, None)
  ).as(TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004)
```

i am getting

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.iteratee.Enumerator[Array[Byte]]{implicit val pec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext}
[error]  required: akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[akka.util.ByteString, _]
[error]         body = HttpEntity.Streamed(responseStream, None, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

HttpEntity.Streamed seems to take three parameters, not one. Try

```
body = HttpEntity.Streamed(responseStream, None, None)
```

if you don't want to specify `contentLength` and `contentType` - these are optional parameters but still need to be defined.

Comment: i want to add "content-type"= TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004 how can i add this in the above code

Comment: You've asked this in another question already. I'm not sure to be honest. Does something like `body = HttpEntity.Streamed(responseStream, None, Some(TextFormat.CONTENT_TYPE_004))` not work (since contentType is one of the optional parameters)?

Comment: Please do keep your questions separate though. If an answer fixes your `not enough arguments for method apply` error, but you have another question (which in your case you do have), you should accept that answer and ask another question separately (which you have done).

Comment: please see my updated question i added your solution